# Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^n\log(x ^ {\frac{k}{2k+1}} )$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I have absolutely no idea on how to tackle this. The log is completely throwing me off, so if you could explain how to deal with a log in a series i would really appreciate it!

Comment: I tried editing, but it still doesn't look right.  Is 2+1, which is 3, supposed to be inside parentheses?  Does it help to know $\log x^p = p \log x$?

Comment: I don't think this is correct as written.

Comment: My bad sorry, still getting used to this! fixing right now!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes that helps! But i'm still confused on taking the summation of a log.

Comment: If $\log x$ is independent of $k,$ you could pull it out of the sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following comments, you need to evaluate
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{2k+1}$$

What is easy is to show that
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{2k+1}\lt \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{2k+0}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2}=\frac{n}{2}$$ which is then an upper bound.

Going beyond is much more complex since
$$S_n=\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{4} \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)$$ where appears [the digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

If $n$ is large, you can use the asymptotics to get
$$S_n =\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\log(n)+\frac{1}{4} \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{4
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ where $\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=2-\gamma -2\log (2)\approx 0.03649$.

Using $n=10$, the exact result would be $\frac{64157087}{14549535}\approx 4.40956$ while the above expansion would give $\frac{219}{40}-\frac{1}{4} (\gamma +\log (40))\approx 4.40848$.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure there is a typo in your expression, but notice how $log(x^a)=alog(x)$ and $\sum \frac{k}{2k+1} log(x) = log(x) \sum \frac{k}{2k+1} = log(x) ( \sum \frac{1}{2} (1 - \frac{1}{2k+1})) $.

Answer (score 1):

Notice this can be written as $$\log(x)\sum\frac{k}{2k+1}$$
Since $x$ is a constant with respect to the sum and $\log(x^a)=a\log(x)$
Can you continue?

Comment: yes I think I'll be able to continue, thanks!

Comment: @Brownie. Are you sure that you need to go further since $\sum\frac{k}{2k+1}$ is not so simple ? May be, you just need a bound.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Well I am currently studying practice problems for an upcoming exam. I haven't encountered a problem like this before and thus far I've always used  partial,arithmetic, or geometric sum. I can't see anything working to further evaluate this so I do need to continue, but It seems I am actually stuck. What is the best path forward?\